# When do you use epsilon in Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, training, epsilon-greedy-policy

In reinforcement learning (DQN) do I use epsilon when I am collecting examples from the environment or do I use epsilon when I am training the Q network and Target network ?

Comment: When taking actions in the environment, assuming you’re using an off-policy algorithm like Q-Learning which DQN is based on.

Comment: great thanks man

Comment: I can write into a proper answer if you find the comment useful?

Comment: yea I would find it very usefull

Comment: People can probably guess what "epsilon" you're referring to (me included), but you should have provided more context. Although there's already an answer, I would still suggest that you edit your post and describe what you mean by "epsilon".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked specifically about DQN, I will talk about Q-Learning. Since it is an off-policy algorithm, we can collect data with any exploratory policy $\beta$ whilst learning about the greedy policy $\pi(s) = \arg\max_aQ(s,a)$. Typically $\beta$ will be an $\epsilon$-greedy, but you do not want to use this when updating your DQN. That is because you update your DQN using the Q-Learning update rule, by training it to approximate $r(s, a) + \gamma \max_a Q_{\bar{\theta}}(s', a)$, where $\bar{\theta}$ are the parameters of the target network.

Comment: thx man it makes sense